# .NET Core 2.0 authorization filter - not working as expected

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to validate an Active Directory role group (using Windows authentication) before executing an API action method in .NET Core 2.0. Something straight-forward [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113243/asp-net-core-authorize-ad-groups-through-web-config) should suit my needs.

My `Program.cs`:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

My `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` (I am referencing a role group in my `appsettings.json` file):

```
services.AddAuthentication();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ValidRoleGroup", policy => 
         policy.RequireRole(Configuration["AuthenticatedGroup"]));
});

services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
 });
```

My `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseMvc();
}
```

And then, I decorate my method with `[Authorize(Policy = "ValidRoleGroup")]`.

When I review the error in Application Insights, I get a message stating `Authorization failed for user: (null)`. Am I missing anything important?

Comment: I added that, and still the same result.

Comment: What I mean is have you configure your authentication to use Active Directory?

Comment: Windows auth? Is that enabled on your server settings? (IIS Express?)

Comment: And is anonymous disabled?

Comment: @DaveBrock take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I am wondering if I want to add AD group authorization at application/site level, what I should do? Thanks