# ASP.NET Active Directory authorization for each web page

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am new to ASP.NET and have been asked to do the following. I have tried looking at a large number of Stack overflow articles in this topic but wasn't quite able to find a specific answer to my situation.

The scenario is the following: the web application is internal to the company.  Within the application, there are many pages that should have varying levels of access based on AD groups. So for example, for one page, if a user is in any of the AD groups A, B, C or D, they will have access. Another page may provide access to a user who belongs to any of AD groups E, F, or G.

Not sure if I read the other Stack Overflow articles incorrectly, but it seemed like they answered the question of providing access to a user who is part of a particular group (single group). For a given web page, I want to provide access to the user if they are part of any of the groups that I specify as permitted to visit that page.

Furthermore, is there an easy way to store the AD group names that I want to have access to each page in a file, and authorize against this file without writing much code? This way if I need to change the groups allowed to visit a particular page, I can just change the list of group names in the file.

Comment: Also one more thing that I forgot to mention is that users shouldn't have to do any logging in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to be automatically logged in, then hosting in IIS is by far the easiest way. Instructions on setting that up are here: [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth)

Locking down certain parts of the site by AD group is pretty easy too. You simply use [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute) above either a whole controller, or just an action, and specify the [`Roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute.roles):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\GroupName")]
```

If you want the group name to be configurable, then you can create a policy for each group that reads the group name from your `appsettings.json` (or anywhere else, really) and you set the [`Policy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute.policy) property of the `AuthorizeAttribute` instead of `Roles`.

Details on how to set that up are in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148149/1202807