# Windows authentication on ASP.NET Core 5 MVC for AD groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to configure Windows authentication in my first ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC app. Only users who are members of certain groups should be able to access the application.

What is the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx?Using+AD+groups+to+authorise+access+to+pages+using+IIS+Windows+Authentication+ASP+NET+Core+2+1), you could try to use [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to authenticate only users from a Active Directory group have access to the page. Make sure you have set correct AD group's name.

Besides, here are some resource about Configure Windows Authentication, you could refer to them:

[Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

[ASP.NET Core Authorize AD Groups through web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113243/asp-net-core-authorize-ad-groups-through-web-config)

Comment: Thank you Zhi,
immediately after authentication and authorization how do you redirect to the home page?

Comment: Please check the Startup.Configure method, by default, the MVC application will use the default route (`endpoints.MapControllerRoute( name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`), and after login success, it will redirect to the Home controller Index page. More detail information about Asp.net Core MVC route, check [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Not so, because if I start from a link to. eg http: //my_app.my_domain/My_Controller/Edit/my_id there is no redirection to the home page. In the past i used the code Response.Redirect ("/") in global.asax session_start.