# Customizing Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, windows-authentication, .net-6.0

I noticed that I can enable Windows Auth in my ASP.NET Core app by enabling `windowsAuthentication` parameter in my `launchSettings.json` file:

```json
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      // ...
    }
```

Is there an easy way to make the authentication a bit more restrictive and allow only users who belong to a specific group in my domain?

I remember implementing this once manually and now I wonder if a feature like this is supported by .NET automatically.

I use .NET6.

### EDIT

Something I have in mind (it's not a valid code, rather loud-thinking):

```cs
app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (userBelongsToGroup(@"MySuperGroup"))
    {
        await next();
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }
});

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows authentication on ASP.NET Core 5 MVC for AD groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671364/windows-authentication-on-asp-net-core-5-mvc-for-ad-groups)

Comment: Hi @mason and thanks for your comment. I'm searching for something more like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191160/how-to-check-if-user-is-member-of-group.

Comment: Anyway, both your link and mine make me think there's no way to make everything work automagically.

Comment: Btw. I've updated my question to make it clearer about my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with authorize filter as below;

```
public class AdminRequired : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
             var claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
            if (somelogic)
            {
                UnauthorizedResult result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
```

add `[TypeFilter(typeof(AdminRequired))]` on the target action

[image]

Comment: Would be nice, but I don't use MVC. My app just returns a single HTML with a bundled JS logic.

Comment: Unless you meant something else than an MVC action. Then can you please tell a bit more details? :)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement my own IApplicationBuilder extension and return 401 if a user does not belong to a specified group:

```cs
public static class CheckAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    public static IApplicationBuilder EnsureADGroup(this IApplicationBuilder app, string groupName)
    {
        return app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var groups = (context.User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity).Groups;
            var names = groups.Select(group => group.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());

            if (names.Contains(groupName))
            {
                await next();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my case it works just fine, but if there are better ways of implementing this, don't hesitate to post a comment and tell me about it :).