# .NET Core MVC 5 Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use Windows Authentication on my .NET Core MVC 5 web app.  To allow specific domain users and an AD group.

I added a web.config in the root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="mydomain\username1, mydomain\username2" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I added this to startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

I added this in my controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"mydomain\ADgroupName")]
[Authorize(Users = @"mydomain\username1")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

In project properties I disabled Anonymous auth and enabled Windows auth.

I added a project reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication`.

When all that is said and done I get the error "Type or namespace 'Users' could not be found".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the error "Type or namespace 'Users' could not be found".

From the [AuthorizeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0), we can see that the `Authorize` attribute only have the Roles and Policy property, without the Users property, so it will show the above error.

If you want to set authorization rights for specified users, you could create a policy for the users, then, in the Controller, set the `Authorize` attribute as below:

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "policyforUser")]
 public class HomeController : Controller
```

More detail information about create policy, see the following links:

[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[ASP.NET Core Authorize AD Groups through web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113243/asp-net-core-authorize-ad-groups-through-web-config)

[ASP.NET Core - Authorization Using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524466/asp-net-core-authorization-using-windows-authentication)

[Using AD groups to authorise access to pages using IIS Windows Authentication](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx?Using+AD+groups+to+authorise+access+to+pages+using+IIS+Windows+Authentication+ASP+NET+Core+2+1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148149/280785 is the one that got me where i needed to be.  thanks!